# rails_admin change dropdown enum with javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I've override rails_admin edit and new form and controller via routes,
and added a javascript to watch for on change of country dropdown,
and refreshed the state dropdown.

but i couldn't find a way to replace the dropdown for state or manipulate the list. 
does anyone know what script is rails_admin using for drop down?

I've tried to manipulate the select dropdown, but its been replaced and hidden by a script.

Comment: You will want to look into http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select

Comment: There is a RailsCast that covers this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised

Comment: those are generic dynamic select, rails_admin is using custom widget filteringSelect, im still trying to figure it out